# Me llegan los dato ,pero cuando quiero pintarlos me dice, que map no es una funcion de data

Tags: reactjs

- Los dato me llegan porque los consoles me devuelve los dato de la API
  lo unico es que cuando le hago al data el .map me dice que no es una
  funcion de data .Y si quiero llamarlos uno a uno tampoco me deja .
  Muchas Gracias por la ayuda

  ````
  class App extends React.Component<any, IState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        data: []
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/pe')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ data })
        })
        .catch(console.log)
    }


    render() {

      const { data } = this.state;
      console.log(data);
      console.log({data});

      if (data.length === 0) {
        return null
      }


      return (```
  ````
- Aqui es donde hago mi map, los console de antes me devuelven todos
  los datos

``

````
        <div >
          {data.map(({ _id, name, lastname, year }) => (
            <tr key={_id} >
              <h5 className="card-title">{name}</h5>
              <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{lastname}</h6>
              <p className="card-text">{year}</p>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </div>

    )
  }
}
```

export default App;
````

Comment: Podrias agregar el console log de data, no sabemos exatamente que es lo que tienes en el, "un objeto" o un "array".

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que estas tratando de usar  [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) que es una función para trabajar sobre arrays sobre algo que no es un array.

Si te fijas en el *debug* de `data` (salida por consola) verás que tienes el array de datos dentro de `data` pero que no es el propio `data`. Tendrás que acceder a él, por ejemplo, con `data[0]`, o algo similar, según la estructura de datos que tenga tu respuesta.